# Golang-Bootstrap library code at application startup

Tags: go, grpc

I have a grpc application, which has a dependency on one of my libraries. I want to execute some library code without explicitly invoking any library function at application startup. The library connects to some external dependencies and I want to be able to check if those dependencies are availbale at startup, so that application does not run into an error at later time.
[image]

afaik init() will not help here since it runs first for a package which is imported in application.This library has 3 packages (P1,P2,P3), all of which use another common package (V) which does the 3rd party dependency check. I do not want to write init() in all 3 packages

Comment: *"I do not want to write init() in all 3 packages"* -- So then write the `init` in package V.